# shell script compare two array of number

Tags: bash

i have two array of numbers, first array have all numbers while the second has a subset of first one, how can i write a script to find the missing number which exist in the first array but not in the second array?

Array 1: 
[0, 1, 2, ..79]
Array 2:
[1, 12, 33, 54,60, 71]

i googled around and tried different approaches i found but none of them worked

1.

```
declare -a array3
for i in "${array1[@]}"
  if [[ "${array2[@]}" =~ "$i" || "${array2[${#array2[@]}-1]}" == "$i" ]]; then
  else
      array3+=("$i") 
  fi
done
```

2.

```
array3=()
for i in "${array1[@]}";do
  skip=
  for j in "$array2[@]";do
     [[ $i == $j ]] && { skip=1; break; }
  done
  [[ -n $skip ]] || array3+=("$i")
done
declare -p array3
```

i m new to bash script, please help!

Comment: Are the elements in each array sorted?  If so, you'll need to  run a loop with, say, index `$i` for `array1` and `$j` for `array2`, and you will either find that `$array1[$i]` is smaller than `$array2[$j`, or equal to it, or larger than it.  If the number in `$array1[$i]` is smaller, print it and increment `$i`; if the values are equal, increment both `$i` and `$j`; if it is larger, increment `$j`.  Stop when you reach the end of either array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to get array differential is using `comm`:

```
array1=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)
array2=(0 1 3 4 6 7 10 12)

comm -23 <(printf "%s\n" "${array1[@]}" | sort) <(printf "%s\n" "${array2[@]}" | sort) | sort -n

2
5
8
9
11
```